# What's the maximum amount of gems you can acquire from a single ore node and is it Mining Luck attribute dependent?

Tags: new-world

Recently I have been leveling up my mining skill and I've noticed that the gem amount drops from gold ore veins range from 1 gem up to 4 gems from a single ore vein. This brought me up to this question:

What is the maximum amount of gems you can get from mining a single ore vein and does the Mining Luck attribute have influence on this?

Comment: I don't know the exact maximum, but gems, the same as the ores themselves, can have the quantity received boosted by using items such as proficiency boosters.

Comment: Update - I've gotten 6 onyx once from mining a gold node once.  So at least 6!

Comment: Thanks for updating - How was your outfit regarding mining and general luck stats when you received the 6 gems in once?

Comment: Pretty sure I didn't have any specific luck modifiers at the time. Just my regular gear.